# Multiple rows data in single textview android

Tags: android, mysql, json

Here is the code i had tried with multiple times to get multiple rows values in a single text view with json.

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
        {

            HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost myConnection = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.5/send-data.php");

            try {
                response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
                str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            try{
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(str);

               for( int i=0;  i <jArray.length(); i++) {
                   json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

               }


            } catch ( JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            try {
                textview.setText(json.getString("survey_textresponse"));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //Hiding progress bar after done loading TextView.
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    }


}
```

when i run php file in chrome directly it shows all values from database while in android app it shows only the first row value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop that you've written for retrieving the values from the JSONArray is not proper. Its only storing the last object while iterating through the loop. You could store the retrieved values in a collection of string. 
Here's an example code you could follow:

```
private class RetrieveTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
    List<String> jsonResults;
    String str;
    JSONObject json;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        jsonResults=new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        for(String data:jsonResults)
            textview.append(data);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost myConnection = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.5/send-data.php");

        try {
            response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
            str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(str);

            for( int i=0;  i <jArray.length(); i++) {
                json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                if(json.optString("survey_textresponse")!=null){
                    jsonResults.add(json.getString("survey_textresponse"));
                }
            }


        } catch ( JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: its working now.. I added textview.setText(........ in onPostExecute method and it worked..

Comment: I just added this line in onPostExecute method with your given code and it's magically start working, textview is now showing all rows data in it

Comment: Are you sure its posting all the rows by using **setText(..)** because if you're looping through the values in the list then it might overwrite the text in the TextView and not append it through setText(..).

Comment: No sir its working fine yet, with no duplicates values

Answer (score 2):

Because you are only storing the last value of `JSONobject` in `json` reference

```
// assume JArray length = 5
for( int i=0;  i <jArray.length(); i++) {
    json = jArray.getJSONObject(i); 
    // only have last object value , in last iteration jArray.getJSONObject(4)
}
```

There can be many solutions to this

- Collect data as list of Values
- Collect in a String or StringBuilder Object

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
// or List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

for( int i=0;  i <jArray.length(); i++) {
    json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    sb.append(json.optString("survey_textresponse")+"\n");
    // or list.add(json.optString("survey_textresponse"));
}
```

and later

```
textview.setText(sb.toString());
// or can collect list as string using loop and display it
```

Comment: pavneet_singh sir, it is populating the last value only, how will it possible to loop through all of json objects?

Comment: @KamranAshiq as i said in answer , you are only looping but you have to collect the data while looping as well , so you can use solutions like  `sb.append`  or `list` to collect data, if you still have issues then post your json response

Answer (score 1):

Your `json` variable contains only last element of `JsonArray` when it is finished. You can display on TextView while retrieving your values from JsonArray.

```
for( int i=0;  i <jArray.length(); i++) {
      json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
      textview.setText(textview.getText() + json.getString("survey_textresponse") + "\n");
}
```

Comment: your code will produce a crash , you cannot update the UI from `doInBackground`

Comment: I added textview.setText(........ in onPostExecute method and it worked..